# Geotif Data Plots rotated on folium

Tags: python-3.x, gis, folium, rasterio

I am using an geotif image downloaded from Earth engine. When downloading the image from Earth Engine, I specified the CRS of 'EPSG:4326'.

According to this post, all things fed to folium get are expected to be passed in 'EPSG:4326'
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362582/coordinate-system-mismatch-in-folium

The data is currently plotting horizontally and it needs to be plotting vertically (see below picture comparison). For a point of reference, the road should be on the east side of the image. Its currently on the south side.

[Improper Rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaNgD.jpg)

[Proper Rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3sNg.jpg)

Here is the code I am using. Can someone spot what I am doing wrong?

```
import folium
import rasterio

in_path = r"filepath"


with rasterio.open(in_path) as src:
    
    img = src.read([4, 3, 2]).astype(np.float32)
    min_lon, min_lat, max_lon, max_lat = src.bounds
    src_crs = src.crs['init'].upper()

bounds_fin = [[min_lat, min_lon], [max_lat, max_lon]]

centre_lon = bounds_fin[0][1] + (bounds_fin[1][1] - bounds_fin[0][1])/2
centre_lat = bounds_fin[0][0] + (bounds_fin[1][0] - bounds_fin[0][0])/2

m = folium.Map(location=[centre_lat, centre_lon],
                    zoom_start = 10,)

#add this to rotate and flip the image!!!! This is the answer to the initial question
img = np.rot90(img, k=3, axes=(2, 1))
img = np.flip(img, axis = 1)


m.add_child(folium.raster_layers.ImageOverlay(img.transpose(2, 1, 0), opacity=1.0, 
                                 bounds = bounds_fin))
```

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a bandaid more than an actual answer, but if I rotate and flip my image, it lines up in the right spot on the map.

I have edited my in initial question to show this answer

i used these 2 numpy functions to achieve this

```
img = np.rot90(img, k=3, axes=(2, 1))

img = np.flip(img, axis = 1)
```